# "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values..." for only a _subset_ of the function domain?

Tags: numerical-integration

What might cause NIntegrate to complain about the integrand evaluating to non-numerical values for only some subset of the function's domain?

I have a pretty complicated function whose (numerical) integral evaluates just fine for say $x_5\leq 1$, but when $x_5 > 1$, I get the above error and I can't understand why.

It's evidently not a problem with feeding NIntegrate symbolic expressions, since the error message can be avoided by choosing a subset of $x_5$, so I don't think there are any non-numerical symbols I'm feeding NIntegrate.

Any thoughts on how this problem might arise would be appreciated. I recognize that I haven't provided a MWE but I hope the above is sufficient.

Update:

This is the code that produces the error:

```
Step2[x5_, En_, k5p_, mD_] := UnitStep[(x5 En)^2 - k5p^2 - mD^2];
Step3[x5_, En_, k5p_, mD_, p1p_, mD_, 
  mC_, \[Theta]_] := (UnitStep[
     k5p^2 + p1p^2 + (p1z + Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + En^2 x5^2])^2 + 
      2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]] /. 
    p1z -> 1/(
      2 (k5p^2 + mD^2 - 
         4 En^2 (-1 + x5))) (-(mC^2 + mD^2 - 2 p1pdotk5p - 
            4 En^2 (-1 + x5)) Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + En^2 x5^2] + 
        En \[Sqrt](mC^4 - 2 mC^2 mD^2 + mD^4 - 4 mD^2 p1p^2 - 
            4 k5p^2 (mC^2 + p1p^2) - 4 (mC^2 + mD^2) p1pdotk5p + 
            4 p1pdotk5p^2 + 
            8 En^2 (mC^2 - mD^2 + 2 (p1p^2 + p1pdotk5p)) (-1 + x5) + 
            16 En^4 (-1 + x5)^2) Abs[-2 + x5])) /. 
  p1pdotk5p -> p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]]

JDel[x5_, En_, mC_, mD_, k5p_, 
  p1p_, \[Theta]_] := (1/(
    p1z/Sqrt[mC^2 + p1p^2 + p1z^2] + (
     p1z + Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + En^2 x5^2])/Sqrt[
     k5p^2 + p1p^2 + (p1z + Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + En^2 x5^2])^2 + 
      2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]]) /. 
    p1z -> 1/(
      2 (k5p^2 + mD^2 - 
         4 En^2 (-1 + x5))) (-(mC^2 + mD^2 - 2 p1pdotk5p - 
            4 En^2 (-1 + x5)) Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + En^2 x5^2] + 
        En \[Sqrt](mC^4 - 2 mC^2 mD^2 + mD^4 - 4 mD^2 p1p^2 - 
            4 k5p^2 (mC^2 + p1p^2) - 4 (mC^2 + mD^2) p1pdotk5p + 
            4 p1pdotk5p^2 + 
            8 En^2 (mC^2 - mD^2 + 2 (p1p^2 + p1pdotk5p)) (-1 + x5) + 
            16 En^4 (-1 + x5)^2) Abs[-2 + x5])) /. 
  p1pdotk5p -> p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]]

dsig23b[gS_, En_, x5_, mC_, mD_, p1p_, k5p_, \[Theta]_] := 
 1/(2 s^3) 1/((2 \[Pi])^3 2 E1) 1/((2 \[Pi])^3 2 E4)
    1/((2 \[Pi])^3 2 E5) 1/P^4 (2 \[Pi])^4 (x5 En^2)/
   Sqrt[(x5 En)^2 - k5p^2 - mD^2]
    JDel[x5, En, mC, mD, k5p, p1p, \[Theta]] Step2[x5, En, k5p, 
    mD] Step3[x5, En, k5p, mD, p1p, mD, mC, \[Theta]] UnitStep[
    mC^4 - 2 mC^2 mD^2 + mD^4 - 4 mD^2 p1p^2 - 
     4 k5p^2 (mC^2 + p1p^2) - 4 (mC^2 + mD^2) p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]] + 
     4 (p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + 
     8 En^2 (mC^2 - mD^2 + 2 (p1p^2 + p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]])) (-1 + 
        x5) + 16 En^4 (-1 + x5)^2] /. {s -> 2^2 En^2, 
   E1 -> \[Sqrt](mC^2 + p1p^2 + 
       1/(4 (k5p^2 + mD^2 - 
           4 En^2 (-1 + x5))^2) (Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + 
            En^2 x5^2] (mC^2 + mD^2 - 4 En^2 (-1 + x5) - 
             2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]) - 
          En Abs[-2 + 
             x5] \[Sqrt](mC^4 - 2 mC^2 mD^2 + mD^4 - 4 mD^2 p1p^2 - 
              4 k5p^2 (mC^2 + p1p^2) + 16 En^4 (-1 + x5)^2 - 
              4 k5p (mC^2 + mD^2) p1p Cos[\[Theta]] + 
              4 k5p^2 p1p^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + 
              
              8 En^2 (-1 + x5) (mC^2 - mD^2 + 
                 2 (p1p^2 + k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]))))^2), 
   E4 -> \[Sqrt](k5p^2 + p1p^2 + 2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]] + 
       1/(4 (k5p^2 + mD^2 - 
           4 En^2 (-1 + x5))^2) (Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + 
            En^2 x5^2] (2 k5p^2 - mC^2 + mD^2 - 4 En^2 (-1 + x5) + 
             2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]) + 
          En Abs[-2 + 
             x5] \[Sqrt](mC^4 - 2 mC^2 mD^2 + mD^4 - 4 mD^2 p1p^2 - 
              4 k5p^2 (mC^2 + p1p^2) + 16 En^4 (-1 + x5)^2 - 
              4 k5p mC^2 p1p Cos[\[Theta]] - 
              4 k5p mD^2 p1p Cos[\[Theta]] + 
              4 k5p^2 p1p^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + 
              8 En^2 (-1 + x5) (mC^2 - mD^2 + 
                 2 (p1p^2 + k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]))))^2),
   E5 -> x5 En, 
   P -> \[Sqrt](mC^2 + mD^2 + 
       2 \[Sqrt](mC^2 + p1p^2 + 
           1/(4 (k5p^2 + mD^2 - 
               4 En^2 (-1 + x5))^2) (Sqrt[-k5p^2 - mD^2 + 
                En^2 x5^2] (mC^2 + mD^2 - 4 En^2 (-1 + x5) - 
                 2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]) - 
              En Abs[-2 + 
                 x5] \[Sqrt](mC^4 - 2 mC^2 mD^2 + mD^4 - 
                  4 mD^2 p1p^2 - 4 k5p^2 (mC^2 + p1p^2) + 
                  16 En^4 (-1 + x5)^2 - 
                  4 k5p (mC^2 + mD^2) p1p Cos[\[Theta]] + 
                  4 k5p^2 p1p^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + 
                  8 En^2 (-1 + x5) (mC^2 - mD^2 + 
                    2 (p1p^2 + k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]))))^2) (x5 En) - 
       2 p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]])};
dsig23dxb[x5_, En_, c_, mC_, mD_, gS_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2 \[Pi] k5p p1p dsig23b[gS, En, x5, mC, mD, p1p, 
    k5p, \[Theta]], {k5p, 0, k5pMax[En, mD, x5]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {p1p, 0, p1pMax2[c, En, k5p, mC, \[Theta], mD, x5]}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3];
dsig23dxb[1.1, 10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10]
```

And here is the error:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (6.26586*10^-12 k5p p1p UnitStep[120.99 -k5p^2] UnitStep[<<8>>+160. (p1p^2+k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]])] UnitStep[k5p^2+p1p^2+2 k5p p1p Cos[\[Theta]]+(Sqrt[120.99 +Times[<<2>>]]+(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])/(2 Plus[<<2>>]))^2])/(Sqrt[120.99 -k5p^2] Sqrt[1/100+p1p^2+<<1>>^2/(4 <<1>>)] Sqrt[<<1>>] <<1>>^2 ((Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]] (39.98 +Times[<<4>>])+9. Sqrt[Plus[<<6>>]])/(2 (-39.99+k5p^2) Sqrt[1/100+p1p^2+1/4 Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>]])+(Sqrt[120.99 +Times[<<2>>]]+<<1>>/(2 <<1>>))/Sqrt[k5p^2+p1p^2+<<1>>+Plus[<<2>>]^2])) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,0.5},{0,1},{0,1}}.
```

Again, this seems to work for all $x_5 \leq 1$, with the exception of 0.01.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "I hope the above is sufficient" Unfortunately, it really isn't. Please at least show the complete error. However, the most likely explanation is that your function simply produces a non-numerical result, as the error seems to state. Evaluate the function with different argument values, and see what the result actually is.

Comment: "non-numerical" can also be `Indeterminate`, `Undefined`, `Infinity`, ...

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you Szabolcs and Rohit for the feedback.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but where are the definitions of `JDel`, `Step2`, and `Step3`?

Comment: @JimB I'm so sorry... question updated.

Comment: Would you also try pasting in the code you've posted in a fresh kernel?  I ask because it seems that the code starting with `JDel[x5, En, mC, mD, k5p, p1p, \[Theta]] Step2[x5, En, k5p, mD] Step3[x5, En, k5p, mD, p1p, mD, mC, \[Theta]]` and ending with `(x5 En) - 2 p1p k5p Cos[\[Theta]])};` is not being used.

Comment: It also looks like the definition of `p1pMax2` is missing.